# Prefetch m2m field values in django-admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have own Auth User model, which inherits from PermissionsMixin. While I'm visiting django-admin page for any instance of that model, I get a lot of db queries (as I have a lot of permissions). The problem lies here, django/contrib/auth/models.py:

```
class Permission(models.Model):

[...]

def __str__(self):
    return "%s | %s | %s" % (
        six.text_type(self.content_type.app_label),
        six.text_type(self.content_type),
        six.text_type(self.name))
```

Every time a permission is displayed on admin page, it makes a query for its content_type.

Question is: can I ensure that for every query involving my Auth User model, especially for that which doesn't come from my code (like django admin) will be run prefetch_related for permissions and their content_types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need this only for django-admin, then you can create your own admin page using techniques described in [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany).

For instance:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

from foo.models import User


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'user_permissions':
            kwargs['queryset'] = Permission.objects.all().select_related('content_type')
        return super(UserAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```